# HTTP Status 500 -

Tags: eclipse, spring, spring-mvc, jar, jboss

i am still new in using java ,SpringFramework.
When trying to Debug my Application i get this error and i cannot interpret it or find where did i do wrong. please any one who knows this error please help.

- i am using **JBoss 7.1**
- **Eclipse** and i have the following Jar files(**commons-dbcp.jar,commons-logging.jar,commons-pool.jar,jstl.jar,log4j-1.2.15.jar,mysql-connector-java-5.1.6-bin.jar,spring.jar,spring-webmvc.jar,standard.jar**)

  HTTP Status 500 -

  ```
  type Exception report

  message

  description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

  exception

  org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is sef.exceptions.DataAccessException: Problem accessing employee repository
      org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:583)
      org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:501)
      javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)
      javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
  root cause

  sef.exceptions.DataAccessException: Problem accessing employee repository
      sef.impl.repository.JDBCProjectRepositoryImpl.listAllProjects(JDBCProjectRepositoryImpl.java:63)
      sef.impl.service.SearchServiceImpl.listAllProjects(SearchServiceImpl.java:54)
      sef.controller.SearchEmployeeController.onInitialSearchFormState(SearchEmployeeController.java:49)
      sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
      sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
      sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
      java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
      org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.doInvokeMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:409)
      org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:132)
      org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:310)
      org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:297)
      org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:875)
      org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:809)
      org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:571)
      org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:501)
      javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)
      javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
  root cause

  org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES))
      org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1225)
      org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:880)
      sef.impl.repository.JDBCProjectRepositoryImpl.listAllProjects(JDBCProjectRepositoryImpl.java:46)
      sef.impl.service.SearchServiceImpl.listAllProjects(SearchServiceImpl.java:54)
      sef.controller.SearchEmployeeController.onInitialSearchFormState(SearchEmployeeController.java:49)
      sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
      sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
      sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
      java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
      org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.doInvokeMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:409)
      org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:132)
      org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:310)
      org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:297)
      org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:875)
      org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:809)
      org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:571)
      org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:501)
      javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)
      javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
  root cause

  java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
      com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1055)
      com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
      com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3491)
      com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3423)
      com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:910)
      com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.secureAuth411(MysqlIO.java:3923)
      com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1273)
      com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2031)
      com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:718)
      com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:46)
      sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
      sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
      sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
      java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
      com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
      com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:302)
      com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:282)
      org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
      org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:294)
      org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1247)
      org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1221)
      org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:880)
      sef.impl.repository.JDBCProjectRepositoryImpl.listAllProjects(JDBCProjectRepositoryImpl.java:46)
      sef.impl.service.SearchServiceImpl.listAllProjects(SearchServiceImpl.java:54)
      sef.controller.SearchEmployeeController.onInitialSearchFormState(SearchEmployeeController.java:49)
      sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
      sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
      sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
      java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
      org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.doInvokeMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:409)
      org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:132)
      org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:310)
      org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:297)
      org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:875)
      org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:809)
      org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:571)
      org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:501)
      javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)
      javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
  note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the JBoss Web/7.0.13.Final logs.

  JBoss Web/7.0.13.Final
  ```

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

The root cause is this:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

Please make sure you can connect to your mysql database by using a mysql client eg Workbench.

Answer (score 0):

In that stack trace your key should be

```
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

It seems you don't have proper credential to access your mysql database.

Check you correctly typed username and password.

Also check that mysql is bound to the 0.0.0.0 address, otherwise you could not be able to connect to it using the physical IP address of the machine.